# Ctrl C breaks the keyboard on Linux

Tags: linux, usb, keyboard, clipboard

I'm using a USB keyboard which works fine on Windows, but on Linux (Ubuntu and Fedora) this happens.

When I press ctrl C to copy some text, the keyboard stops working and I can't type anything anymore. Sometimes it also prints something like this: ctrl^C ctrl^C ctrl^C ctrl^C ctrl^C ctrl^C ctrl^C ctrl^C ctrl^C ctrl^C ctrl^C

What can I do? I couldn't find any information about this on the internet.

I can't see anything on syslog and dmesg either.

Comment: Ive had this problem, Its actually a problem  with the keyboard. Windows doesnt show the errors but it does happen in windows too. I noticed it when connected to a micro controller and it was sending the keypresses to the micro controller repeatedly giving weird behaviour

Comment: @user1281385 But how come it works fine? How can it be sending keypresses and Windows not reacting to them? Doesn't sound correct. Besides it only happens with ctrl c (not with ctrl alone, and not with c alone) and only on Linux.

Comment: @user1281385 Now I tested it on my laptop with Fedora 17 and works fine too. So it's definitely not a problem with the keyboard.

Comment: Get a new keyboard.

Comment: Kindly provide information on how the problem was resolved. It was a mere suggestion to isolate the problem to the specific keyboard in linux. I have seen many hardware problems in both windows and linux that proofs isolation towards the OS and hardware is a necessary move. http://superuser.com/questions/719235/keyboard-stops-working-after-a-few-minutes-on-linux. It also appears you are experiencing other problems with the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

If this happens for both ctrls (left and right) then I would suggest that you check your [Keyboard layout](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-Keyboard-Layout-in-Ubuntu) and your [IBus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_Input_Bus) settings.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently USB keyboard can have conflict with USB mouse depending on the ports you use in Linux. I tried plugging it in many different USB ports until it worked. This command helped:

```
$ sudo lsusb -l
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a terminal open then the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> functionality is different on Linux, it instead [sends a `SIGINT` to the foreground process group](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/xbd_chap11.html#tag_11_01_09). To copy in a Linux terminal you have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.